# The rank of a matrix using the Gaussian method

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I need some hints here:

$1.$ By using the Gaussian method how can I calculate the rank of the following matrix.
$$A=\begin{pmatrix} 1&2&\beta\\ 0&\alpha&1\\ 1&0&2\\ 1&2&1 \end{pmatrix}$$

$2.$ How can I calculate the rank of the above matrix using determinants?

Comment: is there is a technique that allow me to  find a submatrix of size 3×3 with non-zero determinant? or just a random choices

Comment: There are only 4 3x3 submatrices - just compute their determinants.

Comment: You may also solve the problem by noting that the submatrix $B=\pmatrix{1&0&2\\ 1&2&1}$ has rank $2$. Therefore the $\operatorname{rank}(A)$ is either $2$ or $3$. If $\operatorname{rank}(A)=2$, the equation $Ax=0$ and in turn $Bx=0$ have a nontrivial solution. Since $\operatorname{rank}(B)=2$, this solution $x_0$ to the equation $Bx=0$ is unique up to scaling (i.e. the nullspace of $B$ is one-dimensional). So, $\operatorname{rank}(A)=2$ if and only if $Ax_0=0$, and this gives you a necessary and sufficient condition in terms of $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 2 & b\\
  0 & a & 1\\
  1 &0 &2\\
  1&2 &1
\end{pmatrix}~\frac{-R_1+R_3\to R_3}{-R_1+R_4\to R_4},\to \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 2 & b\\
  0 & a & 1\\
  0 &-2 &2-b\\
  0&0 &1-b
\end{pmatrix}$$ if we assume $a\neq 0$ then by $\frac{R_2}a\to R_2$:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 2 & b\\
  0 & 1 & \frac{1}a\\
  0 &-2 &2-b\\
  0&0 &1-b\end{pmatrix}
\frac{2R_2+R_3\to R_3}{-2R_2+R_1\to R_1},\to \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0 & \frac{-2}a+b\\
  0 & 1 & \frac{1}a\\
  0 &0 &\frac{2}a+2-b\\
  0&0 &1-b\end{pmatrix}$$
If $a=-2$ and $b=1$ then the rank is $2$. If $a\neq -2$ and $b=1$ then the rank is $3$. If $b\neq 1$ for all $a\neq 0$ the rank is again $3$. Now do the similar way from the first point assuming $a=0$ to find the possible rank.

Comment: Very nice analysis! +1

Answer (score 1):

1. Row reduce, carefully.  The number of pivot positions is the rank.
2. The rank of a matrix can be calculated by finding the largest invertible submatrix, i.e. the largest submatrix with nonzero determinant.  I.e. if you can find a submatrix of size $3\times 3$ with nonzero determinant, then your rank is 3.

I suspect the rank of this matrix will depend on the parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$, so your answer might need to be parametrized.