# The rank of a bunch of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: linear-algebra

Please help me solve this:

In $\mathbb{R}^4$ how can I calculate the rank of the following vectors: $$a=(3,2,1,0), b=(2,3,4,5), c=(0,1,2,3), d=(1,2,1,2), e=(0,-1,2,1).$$ I know that since $\#\{a,b,c,d,e\}=5$ it's a linearly dependent set in $\mathbb{R}^4$ because $\dim\mathbb{R}^4=4$, but how can I find the right vector? To get rid of it and so on, And how can find the rank using determinant method? I need some hints.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The determinant of a square matrix will tell you if its columns (and/or rows), and the vectors they represent, are linearly independent (determinant not equal to zero).  Here, we want to determine *rank* of a $4\times 5$ matrix, the determinant of which we can't compute.

To find the rank, which at most will be $4$, you need to create a matrix using your vectors for its columns, and put the matrix into [row echelon form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form). That amounts to performing the sort of row-reduction used in the answer to this [earlier question of yours](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/436943/the-rank-of-a-matrix-using-the-gaussian-method). Then you can "read off" the rank of the matrix by counting the number of non-zero rows in the resultant (row-echelon) matrix.

We start with constructing the matrix whose columns consist of the entries of your vectors:

$$\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 3 \\ 
2 & 3 & -1 & 1 & 2 \\
1 & 4 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
2 & 5 & 1& 3 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Now, I'll combine three elementary row operations to begin the reduction:

- $-2R_1 + R_2 \to R_2$
- $-1R_1 + R_3 \to R_3$
- $-2R_1 + R_4 \to R_4$

$$\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 3 \\ 
2 & 3 & -1 & 1 & 2 \\
1 & 4 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
2 & 5 & 1& 3 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix} 
\longrightarrow
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 3 \\ 
0 & -1 & -1 & 1 & -4 \\
0 & 2 & 2 & 2 & -2 \\
0 & 1 & 1& 3 & -3 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

- $2R_2 + R_1 \to R_1$
- $2R_2 + R_3 \to R_3,$
- $R_2 + R_4 \to R_4$

$$\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 3 \\ 
0 & -1 & -1 & 1 & -4 \\
0 & 2 & 2 & 2 & -2 \\
0 & 1 & 1& 3 & -3 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\longrightarrow
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 & -2 & 2 & -5 \\ 
0 & -1 & -1 & 1 & -4 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 4 & -10 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 4  & -10 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Subtracting Row 3 from Row 4 gives us 
$$\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 & -2 & 2 & -5 \\ 
0 & -1 & -1 & 1 & -4 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 4 & -10 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0  & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

which we see has a row whose entries are all zero. The matrix is now in row-echelon form (though not yet reduced row echelon form $\dagger$), having exactly **three non-zero rows.**

Hence the rank of the matrix (and of the set of column vectors) is equal to $3$.

---

$(\dagger)$ We could reduce further to obtain reduced row echelon form:

- $-1\times R_2$
- $\frac 14 \times R_3$

$$\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 & -2 & 2 & -5 \\ 
0 & -1 & -1 & 1 & -4 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 4 & -10 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0  & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix} 
\longrightarrow
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 & -2 & 2 & -5 \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 & -1 & 4 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -5/2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0  & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

- $-2R_3 + R_1 \to R_1$
- $R_3 + R_2 \to R_2$

$$\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 & -2 & 2 & -5 \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 & -1 & 4 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -5/2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0  & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\longrightarrow
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 & -2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 3/2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -5/2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0  & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

The **basis** for the column space spanned by your vectors is given by $$b = \langle 2, 3, 4, 5\rangle^T, c = \langle 0, 1, 2, 3\rangle^T, d = \langle 1, 2, 1, 2\rangle^T$$

And you can test to confirm that $4\times 4$ any matrix with any $4$ of your vectors as columns will have determinant zero.

Comment: lots of matrix typing +1

Comment: Is this helpful, mohamez?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use determinants, then here is the procedure:

1. Write your vectors as rows of a matrix $A$, which will be $5\times 4$.
2. Compute $B=A^TA$, which will be $4\times 4$, and of the same rank as $A$.  This gets you a square, Hermitian, matrix.
3. Compute the determinants of all the leading principal minors of $B$ -- the upper left corners.  $1\times 1$, $2\times 2$, $3\times 3$, $4\times 4$.
4. If you get a nonzero value with the $i\times i$ determinant, but not the next ones, then the rank of $A$ is $i$.